# How to print columns as a table with lists in python?

Tags: python

I need to get this output as rows. How to do that. Below is the code I used to make prints.

```
 print("Horizontal Histogram")
 print("Progress", progress_number, "  : ", star_progress)
 print("Trailer", trailer_number, "   : ", star_trailer)
 print("Retriever", retriever_number, " : ", star_retriever)
 print("Excluded", excluded_number, "  : ", star_excluded)
```

So this is the output I get :

```
Horizontal Histogram
Progress 1   :  * 
Trailer 0    :  
Retriever 0  :  
Excluded 0   :
```

This is the output I need :

```
Progress Trailing Retriever Excluded
    *       *         *        *
                      *
```

I use append to make lists with "*" items inside the dictionary.

```
for x in range(progress_number):
progress_list.append("*")
```

This is how dictionary looks like:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Progress': [progress_list], 'Trailer': 
      [trailer_list], 'Retriever': [retriever_list], 'Exclude': 
      [exclude_list]})
 print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='plain', showindex=False))
```

I tried with pandas and tabulate modules. But I cant print my lists vertically in the dictionary.

```
Progress         Trailer    Retriever    Exclude
['*', '*', '*']
```

Comment: It's unclear why you expect "the output I need", you don't provide values for the variables (`progress_number` etc.) but from what you say you're getting, that doesn't seem to make sense?

Comment: @Grismar those variables have the number that each conditions looped. I didn't put that code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not particularly straightforward.  You have to do this one row at a time, checking each value to see if it still needs to be printed.

```
data = {}
data['Progress'] = 3
data['Trailer'] = 1
data['Retriever'] = 4
data['Excluded'] = 1

titles = list(data.keys())
maximum = max(data.values())

fmt = "{:12}"*len(titles)

print(fmt.format(*titles))
for row in range(maximum):
    histo = ['   *' if v > row else '' for v in data.values()]
    print(fmt.format(*histo))
```

Output:

```
Progress    Trailer     Retriever   Excluded    
   *           *           *           *        
   *                       *                    
   *                       *                    
                           *
```